# How do I show that the Electric field can be written as a composition of an irrotational and a solinoidal one?

Tags: electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I know that Helmholtz tells us that any vector field can be expressed as a superposition af an irrotational part and a solinoidal part. So for the electric field we get
$$
\begin{equation}
  \vec{E} = \vec{E}_i + \vec{E}_s. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
$$
Now the argument to get towards
$$
\begin{equation}
  \vec{E} = -\vec{\nabla} V -  \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
$$
that I see in my book, is to consider the electrostatic case, where $\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$ which gives us $E_i=-\vec{\nabla} V|_i$, and the dynamic case, for which we then get $\vec{E}_s = -\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$. This then results in equation 2. However, I don't see how I can make the argument that simply by looking at both of those cases I somehow am allowed to pull them together into one equation. I feel like there is some information missing to rigorously show this. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You need to say something about the magnetic field $\mathbf B$ if not you do not have enough equations.

Comment: Electric field can always be expressed as sum of a gradient and some appropriate vector field that provides the "rotational" part of the field which gradient can't describe. There is no material statement here about the electric field. The equation 2) is an assumption about properties of the potentials $V,\mathbf A$; this is part of definition of the concept of EM potentials (the other part is $\mathbf B=\nabla\times\mathbf A$).

Comment: Is this not Helmholtz’ theorem? Or am I confusing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain these equations in their general form is to consider by  definition

$$\vec{B} = \nabla × \vec{A}$$

Substitution into Faraday's law get us

$$\nabla × \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \nabla × \vec{A}}{\partial t}$$

$$\nabla ×[ \vec{E} + \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}] = 0$$

And thus since the curl is zero we can assign a scalar potential $ V$
$$\vec{E} + \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} = -\nabla V$$

$$\vec{E} = -\nabla V -\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$$

However these need not to be a Helmholtz decomposition

Using the Coulomb gauge $\nabla \cdot \vec{A} =0$

Taking the divergence, the right term on the RHS equals zero by definition of the Coulomb gauge, Whilst the left remains.

Taking the curl, the curl of a gradient is zero, and the right term is non zero.

And thus this actively demonstrates that the left term is purely irrotational and the right term is purely solenoidal.

This is only true when working in the Coulomb gauge, which I assume you misread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get that, but I don't understand why I am allowed to construct E out of those two parts in the first place.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can, let us start from

$$\mathbf E=\mathbf E_{\rm sol}+\mathbf E_{\rm irr},$$

with

$$\nabla\cdot \mathbf{E}_{\rm sol}=0$$

and

$$\nabla\times \mathbf{E}_{\rm irr}=0,$$

then we can suppose that we have a scalar potential $V$ and a vector potential $\mathbf L$, such that

$$\mathbf E_{\rm irr}=-\nabla V $$
and
$$\mathbf E_{\rm sol}=\nabla\times  \mathbf L .$$

Leaving you with

$$\mathbf E = -\nabla V+\nabla \times \mathbf L.$$

However now you are missing an equation. The equation is Faraday's law
$$\nabla \times \mathbf E= \nabla \times (\nabla \times \mathbf L)=\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\mathbf B.$$

Only if you use $$\mathbf B=\nabla \times\mathbf A,$$

then you can replace $$\nabla \times \mathbf L\to \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\mathbf A.$$

However in order to keep $\mathbf E_{\rm sol}$ solenoidal, you need to impose $\nabla \cdot \mathbf A=0$ which is a specific gauge, Coulomb's gauge.

Comment: I believe there is a missing step when cancelling the curls, there is assumptions you make when doing this as the final expression need not be solenoidal